# String class to combine the first_substring that hold the value of “You are” and the second_substring that hold “pass”

Tags: java

create code using method in String class to combine the first_substring that hold the value of “You are” and the second_substring that hold “pass”.

Comment: String first = "You shall", second = " not pass!"; 
System.out.println(first.concat(second));

Answer (score 0):

You can easily cancatenate strings using the '+' operator
e.g

```
String x = "You are";
String y = "pass";
String xy = x +" "+y;
```